# select array by the value of variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, select

I have some arrays defined in js, and I want to use the variable's value to select which array should I select.

```
// My arrays
var battery = [123, 321, "", ""];
var cables = [234, 432, "", ""];

$(document).ready(function() {

    var file = "battery.jpg";
    var item = file.slice(0, -4); // item = "battery"

    console.log($(item)[0]); // undefined and I was hoping to log "123" - battery[0]
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Variable" Variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bidimensional array.

```
//var mydata=Array()
mydata["battery"] = [123, 321, "", ""];
mydata["cables"] = [234, 432, "", ""];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var file = "battery.jpg";
  var item = file.slice(0, -4); // item = "battery"

  console.log(mydata[item][0]); // undefined and I was hoping to log "123" - battery[0]
});
```

EDIT: As pointed in the comment by Dalorzo it's not an array. I'll keep the mistake (commented) for comments coherency.

Comment: `mydata` is not an array is an object. `mydata=Array()` seems unnecessary

Comment: javascript does not have associatve arrays as @Dalorzo pointed out. Answer is acheiving desired results but is not accurate regarding array vs object  see: http://jsfiddle.net/aFMhx/

Comment: Rigth @Dalorzo, in javascript there are arrays and objects, associative arrays do not exists... But could be someway confusing for a newbie use the right name. Anyway: You are right.

Answer (score 0):

`window["some_string"]` will make a global variable named some_string. like `var some_string`.

so replace

```
console.log($(item)[0]);
```

with

```
console.log(window[file.slice(0, -4)][0]);
```

it will make that string `file.slice(0, -4)`, a global variable.

**----OR----**

```
var item = file.slice(0, -4);
item = window[item]; // make that string a global variable
```

then

```
console.log(item[0]);
```